testing a pkg - cant access pkg outside of dir
I am trying to learn how to create pkg and testing. I researched and found out that for testing you create a seperate folder
power_decos/
├── pytest_cache/
├── venve/
├── decorators/
│   ├── init.py
│   ├── decorator1.py
│   ├── decorator2.py
├── tests/
│   ├── init.py
│   ├── decorator1_test.py
i run in decorator1_test from decorators import decorator1
when i run it it gives me No module named decorators found
i aksed chatgpt but he couldnt help me. i also looked in github for examples but non were found (at least which i could understand)
i am excpecting it to import the decorators pkg

You can resolve this error by adding your project's root directory to the PYTHONPATH environment variable.
If you are on linux you can do this with:
export PYTHONPATH=$(pwd)

Or if you are on Windows:
set PYTHONPATH=%cd%

Alternatively, you can also add the root directory to sys.path on your test files:
import sys, os
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')))
from decorators import decorator1

Hope this will help, if you have more questions feel free to ask.

is this normal to do when creating a pkg, so does anyone who wants to test the pkg need to run such a command?

It's not typical to require modifying PYTHONPATH for testing your package. Instead, you can use pip install -e . to install your package in editable mode. This will create a reference (symbolic link) that points to your project directory, allowing you to import your package without manually adjusting the path.
